# How to Anchor 3 GroupBox grow 2, 1 should be the same size

Tags: .net, winforms, anchor, panel, groupbox

I want to anchor 3 `GroupBox`. First and third `GroupBox`, both contains only 1 `DataGridView`. Second `GroupBox` contains `buttons` and `textboxes`. First `GroupBox` should be to the left side of `Panel`, second `GroupBox` should be in center, third `GroupBox` should be right. First and Third `GroupBox` should be able to grow, second `GroupBox` need to keep position.

For second: `GroupBox` I anchor it to bottom and top. It keep position and grow only in Height - that' what I want.

For first and third `GroupBox` I don't have solution yet. I tried so many combination but I didn't find correct. 
[image]

Comment: Maybe you want a [FlowLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-arranging-controls-on-windows-forms-using-a-flowlayoutpanel)? It should let you keep these things together like you want.

Comment: I did it with `TableLayoutPanel` thank you for idea ;)

Comment: _I did it with TableLayoutPanel_  Have you figured it out?...or are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: @Idle_Mind You can post your, maybe it's better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it isn't the best solution but it worked for me. I used `TableLayoutPanel`.

1. Add `TableLayoutPanel` to Main `panel`.
2. Change property: `ColumnCount` to 3.
3. Change property: `RowCount` to 1.
4. You will have 3 boxes in `TableLayoutPanel`. In each Boxes add 1 `GroupBox`.
5. Change `Dock` property for each `GroupBox` to `Fill`.
6. Click on `Edit Rows and Columns` in `TableLayoutPanel Tasks` [image]
7. Change `Value` and `Size Type` for each `Column`. In my case I put for first and third `Column`: `Size Type` = Percent, `Value` = 50. For second `Column` I put `Size Type` = AutoSize.

So now I get what I want. Thanks to @levelonehuman who give me idea about `Layouts`.